# SFTPoperator get multiple files

Tags: google-cloud-platform, airflow

How to get multiple files from SFTP server using SFTPOperator.
I am able to do it with bash MGET in cloud shell but i don't have any idea about multiple get of SFTPOperator for AIRFLOW

Comment: you can use a combination of `PythonOperator` and [`SFTPHook`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/contrib/hooks/sftp_hook.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
files = [
{'name':'file_name',
'connection': 'sftp_conn_one'},

{'name':'file_name',
'connection': 'sftp_conn_two'},

]


d = DummyOperator(task_id='kick_off_dag')

for file in files:
     task = SFTPOperator(
     task_id = 'get_{0}'.format(file['name']),
     ssh_conn_id = file['connection']
     ...
    )

    d >> task
```

This should produce a task for each of the files you are looking to get. You can even store this list of files in an [Airflow Variable](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#variables)

Answer (score 2):

You can't. `SFTPOperator` only works on a single file or directory. See https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/sftp_operator.py

However, you have at least two options:

- create multiple tasks that each download one file
- subclass `SFTPOperator` and implement your own multi-file get functionality

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished using Airflow's task decorators and [dynamic task mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) inside of your dag. The below code was executed on Airflow 2.5.

```
@task(task_id = get_data)
def get_data():
    return [ '/tmp/file_1', '/tmp/file_2', ... , '/tmp/file_N']

@task(task_id = get_files_from_server)
def get_files_from_server(arg):
    
    download_from_remote = SFTPOperator(
        task_id="download_file"),
        ssh_conn_id=SFTP_CONN,
        local_filepath=arg,
        remote_filepath=arg,
        operation="get",
    )

    download_from_remote.execute(dict())

get_files_from_server.expand(arg=get_data)
```

If you have different paths for the remote file location and local file location you can do something like the following:

```
@task(task_id = get_data)
def get_data(REMOTE_DIR, LOCAL_DIR):
    return [ (LOCAL_DIR+'/file_1', REMOTE_DIR+'/file_1'), (LOCAL_DIR+'/file_2', REMOTE_DIR+'/file_2') ... ]

@task(task_id = get_files_from_server)
def get_files_from_server(arg):
    local_file = arg[0]
    remote_file = arg[1]

    download_from_remote = SFTPOperator(
        task_id="download_file"),
        ssh_conn_id=SFTP_CONN,
        local_filepath=local_file,
        remote_filepath=remote_file,
        operation="get",
    )

    download_from_remote.execute(dict())

get_files_from_server.expand(arg=get_data)
```

The above answer from Viraj does work, but it creates `N` number of separate task which really clutters the UI. The solution provided here will create 1 block and will map `N` number of task to that block keeping things much cleaner. You can still see the status of each individual task as well.